# Getting "unmaximized" bounds of a shell SWT

Tags: java, swt

I need to get the "unmaximized" geometry of a shell that is currently maximized.

If I do

```
shell.setMaximized(false);
r = shell.getBounds();
...do something with r
```

"r" will still be the maximized bounds of the shell. I guess that this is due to the fact that the "unmaximize" signal to the shell is processed later. So the question is: how can I force the system to first process signals and the continue?

I've tried putting display.readAndDispatch() and/or shell.update() before reading bounds but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance, Luca.

Comment: I guess you are trying to do this to remember the size of the shell for the next start of your application. In this case you could just listen to `SWT.Resize` events of the shell and thus keep track of the size of your shell.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```java
shell.setMaximized(false);
Display.getCurrent().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Rectangle r = shell.getBounds();
        // ... do something with r
    }
});
```

You may also want to try and use `Shell#computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)`, see if that helps.

Comment: the big problem is that I need to do so while the shell is being disposed... so when the display.asynchExec runs, the shell is aready disposed... whith this I would need to change the model. I would prefer (if exists) a synch way to do it.

Comment: I've tryed manually disposing the shell in the asynchExec to avoi the shell disposed error. Unfortunatelly even in the asynchExec gives me the maximized size of the shell. Perhaps the OS window manager is still doing something and it is to early. The Thread sleep method doesn't work too. Setting the shell to visible false and then true again, gives me the right size but not right position.

Comment: If the shell is being disposed, it could be that the maximized status never takes effect. Perhaps you need to do this before shell's dispose is called.

Answer (score 0):

...ok I solved it.

The problem is that the OS window manager perhaps performs some animation or something for umaximizing the shell so I came to early in reading new shell geometry.
Also I was doig it while the shell is being disposed...

So I solved in this way.
In disposing event handle I set the event.doit = false to prevent that my shell is disposed when I read the size.
Then I used Timer to give the OS window manager to do its stuff before reading the unmaximized size and finally I dispose the shell manually:

```
        shell.setMaximized(false);      
        final Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        t.cancel();
                        Rectangle r = shell.getBounds();
                                                // ... do something with r
                        shell.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Well perhaps it is not the most elegant way but it works in the end.
Any more elegant solution is wellcome! :)